# dynamic explanation div on dropdown menu change

Tags: javascript

Hi guys I am quite new in javascript, 
I am using a chart.js chart that update itself based on a dropdown button. 
I would like to update as well another div called explanation that give comment on the chart.

gogo is a an object that list explantation id. log.console(gogo) may output [15, 16] or [15, 16, 17, 18]. 
I would need for each explanation id create a new div within the explanation div

I tried :

```
$(".pick-chart").change(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var val = $(this).val();
    if (val != 0) {
                info_process.data.datasets[1].data = info_array[val];
                info_process.update();
                stringval = JSON.stringify(val)
                gogo = opposed_model[val]
                for(var x = 0; x < gogo.length; x++){
                  $("#explanation").append("<b>gogo[x]</b>");
                }
                document.getElementById('explanation').innerHTML = gogo;

            } else {
        info_process.data.datasets[1].data = [];
        document.getElementById('explanation').innerHTML = "";
    }
    info_process.update();
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="col">
          <div class="card box-shad">
            <h5 class="card-header text-center bg-dark text-white">Action</h5>
            <div class="card-body">
              Text - Test
              <div id="explanation">

              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

I do not manage to make it work, any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of issues you have:

1. Instead of `$("#explanation").append("<b>gogo[x]</b>");` do `$("#explanation").append("<b>"+gogo[x]+"</b>");`. Note the way string concatenation is happening.
2. Remove `document.getElementById('explanation').innerHTML = gogo;` this will overwrite the html of #explanation.

Comment: ohh I had no idea about that overwriting thing it is why it messed up all of my tests. Worked properly thx you

Comment: Is there another method instead of append because now when I change the dropdown selection it append it instead of replacing it ..

Comment: @RafiKi you can clear the html before starting the append using `$("#explanation").empty()`